# Implement background tasks to fetch tours data (fetch, put to database, put to search indices)

Tags: java, api, vert.x

I am working with vertx and java, I am new to vertx and i have an  api. please go to link below for a better understanding

```
https://www.tez-tour.com/tariffsearch/hotels?countryId=1104&cityId=345&locale=en (countryId (destination)= Turkey, cityId (city of depature)= Moscow)
```

and a python example script to fetch data from tour api

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import json

async def do_request(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            resp = await response.read()
            #print(str(resp, 'utf-8'))
            parsed = json.loads(str(resp, 'utf-8'))
            print(parsed)

tasks = []

tourCities = {
    /*'Turkey': {
        'cities': [1285,12689,12706,143330,9004247,4433,5736,139343,4434,12691,21301,12705,149827,4151426]
    },*/
    'Austria': {
        'tourId': [308122,3024267,147579,353869,320460,3024283,253138,3026464,3024262,293808,469713,3024272,314293,467029,348518,544505,384331,594027,3025654,258494],
        'params': {
            'hotelClasses': [ // Типы отелей
                {"classId": 269506,"name": "Special Cat.","weight": -9},
                {"classId": 261942,"name": "Chalet","weight": -8},
                {"classId": 253005,"name": "Apts","weight": -6},
                {"classId": 253006,"name": "Pens","weight": -5},

            ],
            "tourTypes": [ // Состав тура
                {"id": 1,"name": "Полный пакет","haveResidence": true,"haveTransfer": true,"haveFly": true,"haveInsurance": true},
                {"id": 2,"name": "Проживание+трансфер","haveResidence": true,"haveTransfer": true,"haveFly": false,"haveInsurance": true},

            ],
            "pansion": [ // Пансион
                {"rAndBId": 15350,"name": "Размещение без питания","weight": 0,"sortOrder": 0},
                {"rAndBId": 2424,"name": "Только завтраки","weight": 1,"sortOrder": 1},
                {"rAndBId": 2474,"name": "Завтрак и ужин","weight": 3,"sortOrder": 3},

            ],
            "tours": [ // Регионы (города, куда ищем тур)
                {"name": "Бад-Кляйнкирхайм","tourId": [308122]},
                {"name": "Баден","tourId": [3024267]},
```

tour operator has a web site (or external REST API) where from we can fetch tour data
each of them provide us with authentication data (login & password) to connect to their tour database (no jdbc, only web based access)

So i have some interface to  be implemented and i should use WebClient but i dont fully understand how to write this method to fetch from the api above
I have two method to implement as follows

```
@Override
    public YuService runParserTask(String tourOperator, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {
          return this;
    } 
    @Override
    public YuService getTaskStatus(String tourOperator, Handler<AsyncResult<ParseTask>> handler) {
        return this;
    }
```

and a parser dto with ENUM status as follows

```
@DataObject(generateConverter = true)
public class ParseTask {

    private String type;

    private Status status;

    public ParseTask(String type, Status status) {
        this.type = type;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ParseTask(JsonObject json) {
        ParseTaskConverter.fromJson(json, this);
    }

    public JsonObject toJson() {
        JsonObject json =  new JsonObject();
        ParseTaskConverter.toJson(this, json);
        return json;
    }
```

Can i get an explanation may be a bit of code to help me get a better understanding on how to implement this method